# Is it possible to check if string contains English word using python?

Tags: python

So I am trying to make automation solution for one of my project and I am using Python/Django as it is web app. I am trying to find an English word in list of strings and for particular, in bitcoin addresses. The project is about vanity address so I am trying to find whether a bitcoin address has english word in it or not. I know it sounds crazy but I am curious to know if it is possible or not. So for example,

```
1GOOGLEzZDwTGhXJwPSapWtViWJf2NJYyt
1vsDRvApplemzFVj8ALj6mfBsbifRoD4mi
1NmD9HtNHYjtkncsT1bXW1j84jg9MV8VzD 
1mFAceBookzFVj8ALj6mfBsbifRoD4miY3
1mzFVj8ALj6mfBsbifRoYaHOOeD4miY36v
1NmzD3YLFsMpPQEsCVCjanAiN1trk3tURL
```

So first address contains Google, second contains Apple, third contains nothing, fourth contains Facebook in it and fifth contains Yahoo in it and sixth contains URL which i don't consider english word but like Google and Facebook it is one of a kind word. So it it possible to check what kind of words are in one bitcoin address using python? An address can have zero or multiple possible words in it and I would like to know which words if possible.

If this is possible, can anyone tell me which library I can use? I am working with Python3 and Django 2.

P.S. I am not specifically looking for Google, Facebook, Apple, yahoo in it! It was just an example. I want to check if an address contains english word or not which means it can have `monkey` or `donkey` or any english word.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to find a particular word in a bunch of addresses or are you trying to detect if a particular address has any English word whatsoever?

Comment: Not a particular address first of all, so in every address I can scan, I want to scan if it has any english word in it or not. Zero or more english word in the address.

Comment: @gilch I know that it sounds crazy and will take a lot of processing power but that is second thing to worry about as right now I am looking for an answer that is it possible or not and if it is than how can I do that!

Comment: Are you asking if f it’s _possible_ (which, of course, it is) or if is possible _in a reasonable amount of time_?

Comment: Hello @BryanOakley, when I asked possible I meant that I want to find possible English word(s) from a Bitcoin address. It is like those puzzle where you see bunch of alphabets in a square and whatever word you see first is reflects your personality or you want in life etc. So for a bitcoin address you might see a word, I might see different word and some other person might see both of our words and may be one or two more different words.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a list of all English words you care to detect. There are a number of places to get these. I'd suggest looking at the dictionary files for a spellchecker, like aspell, since you don't care about the definitions. Aspell [has a command to dump wordlists](https://www.joe0.com/2018/02/13/how-to-dump-and-convert-aspell-dictionary-to-wordlist-or-searchable-mysql-mariadb-database/).

```
aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand > words.en.txt
```

Next, get an iterable of the words. You'll probably want to filter out trivially short words like `a` and `I`, and any words with special characters that can't appear in an address. Format the word list into a regex with alternations, i.e. `'|'.join(wordlist)`.

Since Python's backtracking regex engine doesn't handle alternations efficiently, you'll want a faster engine. Try [`pip install rure`](https://pypi.org/project/rure/), which uses Rust's regex engine, and use that to compile the regex instead. (See Rust's regex [optimization guide](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/blob/master/PERFORMANCE.md).) If you care about *which* word it found, you can wrap the whole regex in `()` to make it a capturing group.

Then just run the compiled regex (maybe case-insensitive) against each address in turn. If it matches, you'll get the word.

Comment: Thanks @gilch for detailed answer. I will look into it. :D